# How to display taxonomy content on node--page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I'm working in Drupal 7, and trying to render a map & construct a list based off of content in a certain taxonomy. For example:

- Various locations are created as individual nodes, with information (title, location, phone number, hours, etc.) attached.
- One field in the location nodes is a taxonomy term: market. For example, East Coast or West Coast.

Currently, the only location this map exists is on a taxonomy-term--markets template, which pulls in all variables about each location in the appropriate market.

What I want to do is display a map on a different page (node--page) by selecting the market manually as a related field type. I can get the market name to appear, but I cannot get any information about the child locations! How do I do this? I've tried using a view and a block, but the template for the map is quite involved — and my understanding (which could be wrong) is that the variables I need to access cannot be "templated" from within the view/block system.

Anybody know how to go about accessing node information for a given taxonomy on a page template? Thanks!

Comment: you can use preprocess to add to `$variables` information about taxonomy

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Install, enable it and then create a new view page. and on filter criteria add   `Content: Has taxonomy term`. That way you could load nodes or get nid/s and load the node content.

Answer (score 0):

Your map exists currently on `taxonomy-term--markets` which is I believe a taxonomy term template level rather than a page template level. By default the taxonomy page will be displaying the list of node that relate that `tid` term. On your `template.php` file add a taxonomy template preprocess [function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/template_preprocess_taxonomy_term/7.x)

```
function your_theme_preprocess_taxonomy_term(&$variables) {
     $nodes = taxonomy_select_nodes($variables['term']->tid);
     var_dump($nodes);  
}
```

The `$nodes` will give you a list of `nid`s which you can `node_load` from them, will give you access to node info.

On `page--node--page` template level if you know the taxonomy term `{tid}` than you can create a page preprocess function. So on your {your_theme}/template.php

```
function your_theme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
     //Assuming you know your {tid}
    $variables['mynodeinfo'] = taxonomy_select_nodes({tid}));
}
```

And on your `page--node--page` template output it by

```
var_dump($nodeinfo);
```